# 'Do you have books' vs 'Do you have any books'

Tags: determiners

Is it mandatory to use **any** in questions and negative sentences when using plural nouns? I have found a [site](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/do-you-have-children-vs-do-you-have-any-children-is-there-a-difference) that says it is not necessary. If I omit **any** will that be grammatical?

Here are some examples:

1. Hey Peter, do you have '**any**' books?
2. Last month, I visited a rain forest. I did not see '**any**' animals there.

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Thank you. Although the question is almost similar but mine has a little more description. Can you or anyone please clear my doubts?

Comment: @user332660 You do not have doubts.  You have questions. Doubt is something else.

Comment: "any" emphasizes the difference between 0 and 1, and the possible expectation of none. If just some quantity in general, you can omit it or use "some".